# Error: [$injector:modulerr] when trying to use $modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ng-animate

I am new to angular and was trying to get a modal window and following http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2806-creating-a-simple-modal-system-in-angularjs.htm

But when I load the page, I get following error -

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=drag-and-drop&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.15%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Ddrag-and-drop%0AR%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A417%0AOd%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A412%0Aa%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A53%0AOd%2F%3C%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A1%0Ag%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A46%0Ar%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A300%0Ag%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A399%0Aab%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A135%0Auc%2Fd%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381%0Auc%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A179%0AJd%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A1%0A%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A250%3A429%0Am.Callbacks%2Fj%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A27239%0Am.Callbacks%2Fk.fireWith%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A28057%0A.ready%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A29889%0AJ%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A30255%0A
```

Now I did some research and found it may be due to injection as proper modules cannot be found

Here is my controller initialization -

```
var App = angular.module('drag-and-drop', ['ngDragDrop']);

App.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope, $modal) {...});
```

Now I tried all these options but they keep on giving different errors

```
var App = angular.module('drag-and-drop', ['ngAnimate']);

App.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope, $modal) {...});
```

Then defining like this -

```
App.controller('oneCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {
```

My scripts that I have included are -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="{!$Resource.AngularDragDrop}" ></script>
```

Any help will be very pleasing for me

THanks,
Ray

Comment: Looks like you have not included script for `ngDragDrop`

Comment: it is there.,Updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `$modal` object which belongs to [**angular-ui-bootstrap**](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) library, if you really wanted to use the modal popup, I'd suggest you to add [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) library in your project.

After adding library reference you need to add ui.bootstrap module reference in your app dependency.

```
var App = angular.module('drag-and-drop', ['ngDragDrop', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Or if you don't want that modal over there you could remove `$modal` from controller dependency.

As your given link has a code which inject `modals` dependency and there is `modals` custom service defined in that code. You need to add that service in your app.

Comment: If I take look at the link of tutorial, there they have used  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/angularjs/angular-1.3.15.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/angularjs/angular-animate-1.3.15.min.js"></script>


and 

 app.controller(
            "AppController",
            function( $scope, modals ) {

What will modals here represent?

Comment: I think I may want to use something different rather than angular ui as mentioned in http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2806-creating-a-simple-modal-system-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: @KaushikRay did you looked at the code specified in the article.. you have not added `modals` services..